# Why Modifier.weight() doesn't work in a LazyColumn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I was trying to create a `LazyColumn` containing Cards, each containing 3 elements: a Row, a Divider, and another Row. The issue arises when I use `Modifier.weight(0.25f)` within one of the Rows. I intended the second Row to have a size equal to 1/4 of the first one. However, that Row simply disappears. Why is that? I know I could just fix the size of the second Row as well, but i want to understand why in this way isn't working properly

```
LazyColumn(modifier){
        items(topTens){
            Column {
                Row(
                    Modifier
                        .height(20.dp)
                        .background(Color.Magenta)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Prova1")
                }
                Row(
                    Modifier
                        .weight(0.25f, false)
                        .background(Color.Green)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Prova2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

The problem seems to happen only if I nest rows into Column. If nest columns into row the problem doesnt happen. So if I have somehting like

```
LazyColumn(modifier=modifier.fillMaxHeight()){
        items(topTens){
            Row {
                Column(
                    Modifier
                        .width(100.dp)
                        .background(Color.Magenta)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Prova1")
                }
                Column(
                    Modifier
                        .weight(0.25f, false)
                        .background(Color.Green)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Prova2")
                }
            }}
    }
```

Everything works as intended and I see 2 Columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario, the issue arises because when a weight is applied in a column scope, the column divides the vertical space remaining after measuring unweighted elements and distributes it according to the weights. However, when a column is a child of a scrollable column, and the calculation of remaining vertical space made by .weight becomes infinite so Jetpack Compose ignores the weight.

**But why doesn't this issue occur when Rows are used instead of Columns?**

- The distinction lies in the fact that columns arrange their items vertically, while rows arrange them horizontally. When a weight is used in a column scope, it divides the vertical space remaining after measuring unweighted child elements, distributing it according to the weight. In contrast, when a weight is used in a Row scope, it only concerns itself with dividing the horizontal space. In this case, the vertical space being infinite is not a problem.

The solution to this problem is to avoid making the remaining vertical space infinite for the column that having a weight.
you can do that by fixing a height for that column.

```
Column(Modifier.height(200.dp)) {
            Row(
                Modifier
                    .height(80.dp)
                    .weight(1f)
                    .background(Color.Magenta)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Prova1")
            }
            Row(
                Modifier
                    .weight(0.25f, true)
                    .background(Color.Green)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Prova2")
            }
        }
```